# How to search/replace text in directory and subdirectories

Tags: python

I've searched and searched but haven't found a simple solution.
Lots of fully-complete tutorials and PhD disertations, but I don't want to read pages of stuff...

**I want to search & replace a text item in all files and subdirectories located in a directory.**
I have code that works to search & replace in selected files and in all files in a parent directory by using either of these `os.scandir()` arguments:

```
 '.'
 os.getcwd()
 ()
```

(They get same results - replacing only what's in the parent drectory, but not in subdirectories or text files.  I want to Replace ALL the specified text item strings /text.)

**Clarifying:** It works on any selected file, but not in items *not* located in the parent directory.

I have a directory with Python codes, text files, and subdirectories (folders) that contain more text files and more subdirectories.
Naturally, I've tweaked and tweaked, but I'm not getting what I want (though, I know it's simple...)

The tree looks something like this:

[image: screen shot of directory tree]

Here's a snippet of relevant code:

```
if(FLAG_Option == 2):
    with os.scandir( ) as directory:  # was   '.' and theDIR, hum
        for item in directory:
            if not item.name.startswith('.') and item.is_file():
                with open(item, mode="r+") as file:
                    data = file.read()
                    # print(data)  # Before text replaced
                    data = data.replace(search_text, replace_text)
                    file.write(data)
                    print(data)  # After text is replaced

                with open(item, mode="w") as file:
                    file.write(data)
```

Comment: Better to use `os.walk('My_Code_DIR')` to scan through the directory tree. Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) . An other issue with your code is that you rewrite the file which will be resource intensive operation. So I will suggest you to consider **fileinput** library. Read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html)

Comment: Again, I tried Walking with many variations. Just did as you suggest but, same results as with os.scandir('.') etc.... Only changes All the files located in the Dir here the Code is.  I need to change the Sub-Folder text files, too!   I'm not yet worried about negative side of using resource intensive coding - can fix that later.  Main current focus is Replacing Text in Sub DIR and it's files ... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do what you wanted.

```
import os

def scan_dir(root_dir, search_text, replace_text):
    if os.path.exists(root_dir) and os.path.isdir(root_dir):
       tree_paths = [os.path.join(dirs, files[-1]) for dirs, name, files in os.walk(root_dir, topdown=True, followlinks=False)]
       for file in tree_paths:
           with open(file, 'r+') as f:
               content = f.read()
               content = content.replace(search_text, replace_text)
               f.write(content)
    else:
        return

root_path = 'C:\Training\Data'
search_txt = 'python'
replace_txt = 'text'

scan_dir(root_path, search_text, replace_txt )
```

**UPDATE**

`os.walk()` returns a tuple of three path values for each iteration. `directory path`, `directory name` and list of each `files` in the current directory. So `for each` `walk` the method yields one or more file names. When there is multiple files are there in a directory or sub directory the above code lacks reaching to every files.
Below code can solve the issue.

```
import os


def scan_dir(root_dir, search_text, replace_text):
    if os.path.exists(root_dir) and os.path.isdir(root_dir):
        for dirs, name, files in os.walk(root_dir, topdown=True, followlinks=False):
            for file in files:
                content = None
                                if not file.startswith('.'):
                    current_item = os.path.join(dirs, file)
                    with open(current_item, 'r') as f:
                        content = f.read()
                        content = content.replace(search_text, replace_text)

                    with open(current_item, 'w') as b_file:
                        b_file.write(content)
    else:
        return


root_path = 'C:\\Training\\Data'
search_txt = 'text'
replace_txt = 'python'

scan_dir(root_path, search_txt, replace_txt)
```

I have tested with multiple files in a directory and sub directories up to the depth of 3 child directories. I also tested with the case when more than one sub directories each containing their own sub directories and etc.

My directory structure look like the following

```
C:\Training\Data    root directory
     |
      root1.txt
      root2.txt
      sub              sub directory
       |
        sub1.txt
        sub2.txt
        sub2           sub directory
         |
          sub21.txt
          sub22.tx
          sub3         first sub directory
           |
            sub31.txt
            sub32.txt
          sub4         second sub directory
           |
            sub41.txt
            sub42.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over dirs and subdirs with `os.walk`:

```
import os


def replace_text_in_files(rootdir, search_text, replace_text):
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('txt'):
                file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    data = f.read().replace(search_text, replace_text)
                with open(file_path, mode='w') as f:
                    f.write(data)


replace_text_in_files(r'D:\PROGRAMMING\temp\so\76936763', 'aaa', 'bbb')
```

Comment: Thanks but, it didn't work. I tried Walking many times before posting question. I also replace 'f' with 'file' to be sure but, still won't work... Also tried Hard-Coding the File's Parent, as in   'os.walk('MOD_File_Fix2')'

Comment: Correction (wrong File in previous Comment.  Hard-Coded this:  'os.walk(My_Code_DIR') it  Didn't work...

Comment: `Thanks but, it didn't work` — what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Need to just recursively call the function on sub-directory if item is directory when searching parent.

```
   def search_directory(dir):
                   ...
            for item in directory:
                if ... and item.is_file():
                    ...
                elif item.is_dir():
                    search_dirctory(item)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your posts.  I played with all of them, and while different aspects produced partial solutions, the one (full / complete code, not posted) does what I need as far a marching down the files / contents of the directories and supdirectories.

And it is much cleaner/simpler...  Adding the search/replace is the easy part;  so, below is the code up to the part needing search/replace.

I will include specific file-types to not take action on (in conditional statements).

```
import os

dirpath = 'the_path_to_the_desired_DIR'
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk('.'):
    print(f'Found directory: {dirpath}')
    for file_name in files:
        print(file_name)
```

Comment: Glad to know that you have got solution. How ever, you need to approve an answer or suggest an edit so that people with same problem can use it in the future. What you showed here doesn’t seem complete answer according to your question

Comment: Thanks - I Approved your answer and it's the full solution so, I'll use it!   I appreciate your having stayed with it and posting a good solution.